# Image styles: Color to alpha?

Tags: media

In GIMP there is a very useful operation "Colors > Color to alpha..".
It lets you specify a color (e.g. white), and then replaces this color with transparency.

The effect is written such that if you would display the resulting image on top of a background of the chosen color, it would give you the original image back.
(or this is how I understand it)

I was trying to achieve the same effect with Drupal 7 image styles.
There is an effect "Alpha transparency", but the explanation is horribly confusing. Otherwise there doesn't seem to be anything close.

EDIT: Some useful links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282714/how-to-change-the-alpha-of-a-pixel-without-changing-the-resulting-color
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280902/what-algorithm-is-behind-the-gimps-color-to-alpha-feature

Comment: I used [`imagecolortransparent()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php) to do something very similar recently, might be worth a look. Should be simple enough to convert that logic to a style plugin...

Comment: i suspect this is not quite the same.. have a look at the links.